# Empty cells and html result in tables of Word API Javascript

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office365api, word-addins

The following code should count the paragraphs and in each paragraph the function placeComponents uses a patter to determine whether the paragraph contains a certain text. (It's actually more complicated but this summarizes what the code does.)

```
  await window.Word.run(async context => {
  const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs
  context.load(paragraphs, 'text,tableNestingLevel,contentControls/title')
  await context.sync()

  let emptyParagraphTable = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
    console.log('Is the paragrap in table?', paragraphs.items[i].tableNestingLevel !== 0, i, paragraphs.items[i].text)
    if (paragraphs.items[i].tableNestingLevel !== 0 && paragraphs.items[i].text === '') {
      emptyParagraphTable += 1
    } else {
      const id = i - emptyParagraphTable
      await placeComponents(paragraphs.items[i], id)
    }
  }
})
```

The document content looks like this

[image]

and the code log:

[image]

As you can see, some cells that not appear in the table are recognized as paragraphs. So I count them.

But if I export the word doc to html the "empty" paragraphs not appear (as you can see into the next html code). So I try to search but `<p>` by order it not possible to do correctly:

```
   <tr>
        <td width=154 valign=top style='width:115.4pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>NAME</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=161 colspan=3 valign=top
          style='width:121.05pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  border-left:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>SURNAME</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=145 valign=top
          style='width:108.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  border-left:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>AGE</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='height:12.5pt'>
        <td width=154 rowspan=2 valign=top
          style='width:115.4pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  border-top:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>Francho</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=81 rowspan=2 valign=top
          style='width:60.5pt;border-top:none;  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>García</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=81 colspan=2 valign=top
          style='width:60.55pt;border-top:none;  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>Villarroya</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=145 rowspan=2 valign=top
          style='width:108.75pt;border-top:none;  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>40</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='height:12.5pt'>
        <td width=40 valign=top
          style='width:30.25pt;border-top:none;border-left:  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>Juan</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=40 valign=top
          style='width:30.3pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;  border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>Berna</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=154 valign=top
          style='width:115.4pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  border-top:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>____</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=161 colspan=3 valign=top
          style='width:121.05pt;border-top:none;  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>&nbsp;</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=145 valign=top
          style='width:108.75pt;border-top:none;border-left:  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
          <p class=111 style='margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm'><span lang=EN-US>_____ /_____</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

How can I skip the "empty" cells? How can I pick out them between the correct cells?

Comment: The content of the third image is not legible (too small). On Stack Overflow you should post text of code and system messages, not images. Could you please replace that third image with (representative) text and format it using the code tool? Also, it would help to see a picture of the resultant HTML in order to compare it with the Word table.

Comment: Note that ***every*** cell in a Word table contains a paragraph. A seemingly "empty" cell contains at least two characters: ANSI 13 + ANSI 7 (a paragraph and cell-structure character). These are combined in the "blue sunshine" visible in each cell. There is no such thing as a truly empty cell (21). In addition, Word still counts *merged* cells (15, 16, 19) as cells.

Comment: I apologize again. Already I have done the changes. I hope that this time will be correct. :,(

Comment: @CindyMeister The question in fact is how to count this _merged_ cells or much better how pick out between the _normal_ cells and the _merged_ cells.